# Java List, Counting non-zero attributes of Object, by group of 3

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, filter, java-stream

I have a `ArrayList<Fileline>` and inside `Fileline` a function

```
public Double getValue() {
    ...
    doing stuff
    ...
    return value;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is return the `count` of any non-zero `getValue()` of a group of 3 filelines.

Let's say I have `List<Fileline> filelines` of `filelines.size() = 12` and their respective `getValue()` are `0,0,0, 0,1,2, 0,3,0, 4,5,5` then the `result` I'd like would be 3, all are valid expect the first group.

If it was group of 1 fileline I could `filter` and `count` like this :

```
long resultCount = filelines.stream().filter(x -> x.getValue() > 0).count();
```

, but the fact that it's by group of 3 is causing me problem.

Is the best approach to split the list into multiple 3 elements sublists or is their a more elegant way?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Remember that we can't see your codebase. Please try to be as clear as possible. What is `Fileline`? Is this a line read from the file? What is `ElementId`? What does the `ArrayList` contain? Does each index position contain 1 line? What's with the comma seperator? and so on..

Comment: @CKing I'll try to change my question, but it really has nothing to do with my Objects. In fact I can remove `ElementID` without changing anything to the question

Comment: Do you have control over the format of the file? If so, would it not be easier to format the file differently?

Comment: @Benoit Just post the bare minimum information that forms the question. If `ElementId` is not important, then get rid of it. Explain the rest of the parts that we don't know about. I am still confused. *Let's say I have 12 Fileline and their respective getValue*. What does this mean?  *If it was each fileline I could filter and count*. What does this mean?

Comment: @RogueCSDev I receive the file as it is

Comment: Split the task into three simple subtasks: 1. Create a class FileLineGroup, containing 3 FileLines, and a method hasNonZeroValue() returning a boolean; 2. Transform your List<FileLine> containing 12 elements into a List<FileLineGroup> containing 4 elements. Filter and count that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by three mapping the range of indices to the sublists like this:

```
List<Fileline> filtered = IntStream.range(0, list.size()/3)
    .mapToObj(n -> list.subList(n*3, n*3+3))
    .filter(subList -> subList.stream().anyMatch(fl -> fl.getValue() != 0.0))
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I assume that you want to flatten the groups back, so I added the `flatMap` step. Alternatively you can leave them grouped if it's better in your case:

```
List<List<Fileline>> filtered = IntStream.range(0, list.size()/3)
    .mapToObj(n -> list.subList(n*3, n*3+3))
    .filter(subList -> subList.stream().anyMatch(fl -> fl.getValue() != 0.0))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you just need to count such groups, replace the `collect` step with `count` and merge map and filter into single step:

```
long count = IntStream.range(0, list.size()/3)
    .filter(n -> list.subList(n*3, n*3+3).stream().anyMatch(fl -> fl.getValue() != 0.0))
    .count();
```

Comment: The two last operations should be replaced by count(), if I understand the question correctly.